# Elasticsearch set default number of replicas to 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to set the index.number_of_replicas to 0 for all new indexes created without templates.

This can no longer be done through elasticsearch.yml. The suggested way is to use templates, however I'm looking for a way to do it without templates.

Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: The only way I know of is by using index templates.

Comment: @Val If I create a default Index Template for [*], will other Index Templates be able to overwrite it afterwards? Or there can only be a single template per index?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Easier to show an example, see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I know is by using index templates.

Note that there can be as many [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) as you want, not only one per index. You control their order (i.e. how they overwrite each other) by using the `order` setting:

```
# This template is low priority and applies to all indexes:
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["*"],           <-- applies to all indexes
  "order": 0,                        <-- lowest priority
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}

# This template has a higher priority and only applies to indexes foo*:
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["foo*"],        <-- only applies to foo*
  "order": 3,                        <-- higher priority
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1          <-- overrides the number of replicas from base template
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it index template ? I am asking Because index template uses JSON and JSOIN cand include "PUT _template/template_1".
If it's for dev tools why are you mentioning "templates" ?

Comment: Those are sample reproducible commands to be run in Dev Tools